# Do weapon aspect effects count as a 'status curse' for Privileged Status bonus?

Tags: hades

Some weapon aspects, such as Gilgamesh and Charon, allows you to place an effect on an enemy.  For instance, the maim effect of Gilgamesh causes enemies to take and deal additional damage, followed by a 400 damage burst similar to Doom after 4 seconds.  Do these effects count towards the required 2 statuses that triggers bonus damage on the enemy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, those effects do not count towards the required 2 statuses. All Status Curses come from Olympian Gods. Every Status Curse will say *Status Curse* at the start of the tooltip. Each Olympian God (apart from Hermes) has one Status Curse.

For comparison:

Jolted, Zeus' Status Curse

[image: Jolted tooltip]

Maim, the effect inflicted by the Aspect of Gilgamesh

[image: Maim tooltip]

The status curses are:

- Weak (Aphrodite)
- Hangover (Dionysius)
- Doom (Ares)
- Chill (Demeter)
- Jolted (Zeus)
- Ruptured (Poseidon)
- Exposed (Athena)
- Marked (Artemis)

[Status effects - Hades Wiki](https://hades.gamepedia.com/Status_effects)